# Does a length-contracted black hole have less entropy?

Tags: black-hole-thermodynamics

When objects move with a velocity, they are squashed in the direction of motion. Therefore, it seems as though a moving black hole would be length contracted and have a smaller surface area. Is there any way to understand this in terms of black hole entropy, that is, does a moving black hole have less entropy?

Comment: What if entropy density is also increased along the direction of motion? Formulations of black hole entropy exist that are Lorentz-invariant, e.g. https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.93.051303.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about motion of an object, you need to specify a reference frame.

Moving objects are not "squashed in the direction of motion," they simply appear to be different lengths to observers in differently moving frames.

In calculating the object's entropy, the natural frame to use is the one where the object is not moving. So, it makes no sense to say that "a moving black hole has less entropy."